# Knockoutjs mapping doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

This is my http://jsfiddle.net/ENMGp/468/ sample code

My Json object

```
{
   "VehicleModels":[
      {
         "Name":"Model 1",
         "Model":{
            "MakeName":"Ford"
         },
         "Styles":[
            {
               "StockImage":"http://google.com"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":"Model 2",
         "Model":{
            "MakeName":"Ford"
         },
         "Styles":[
            {
               "StockImage":"http://bing.com"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to access Styles array, but my viewmodel doesn't allow me to access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your `Styles` properties is array, you can access it by `Styles()[0].StockImage`

1. Here is the working version for **object**: http://jsfiddle.net/ysN4m/
2. And here is the working version for **array**: http://jsfiddle.net/c6Qvq/

And the other changes is, use `<span></span>` instead of `<span />`

Comment: Your array version gives a runtime error (Styles[0] is undefined)

Comment: Ahh, sorry my fault. I'm missing `()` Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks mate for pointing out this "<span></span> instead of <span />"